# GP4 on a PIC12F683 microcontroller not functioning correctly

Tags: microcontroller, pic, mplabx

I am attempting to make a project wherein I have some LED's on pins GP2 and GP4 of a [Microchip PIC12F683](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41211d_.pdf) microcontroller flashing in a simple pattern. The problem is that I cannot write to GP4 correctly, or that it at the very least won't respond to me writing to it. As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with my configuration registers, and when I tested the pin with a multimeter, it reads at about 2.5 volts. When I probed the pin with an oscilloscope, it seems to have a sine wave floating on the top. This might be interference of some kind, but to be honest, I have no idea. I'm using MPLAB X and a PICKIT 3 to program the controller.

TL;DR: GP4 doesn't work and I have no idea why.

My code:

/* 
     * File:   newmain.c
     * Author: Malachi
     *
     * Created on May 3, 2018, 4:38 PM
     */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
// PIC12F683 Configuration Bit Settings
// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = EXTRCCLK  // Oscillator Selection bits (EXTRC oscillator: External RC on RA5/OSC1/CLKIN, CLKOUT function on RA4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF       // MCLR Pin Function Select bit (MCLR pin function is GP3)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown Out Detect (BOR enabled)
#pragma config IESO = ON        // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal External Switchover mode is enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = ON       // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is enabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.

#include <xc.h>


/*
 * 
 */

int main(void) {
    OSCCON = 0b01110001;
    TRISIO = 0b00001000; // all bits are 0, setting them as outputs (except for GP3)
    //NOTE: WHEN YOU CHANGE GP3, BE SURE TO CHECK THE MCLR BIT AT THE TOP IDIOT
    CMCON0 = 0b00000111;
    ADCON0 = 0b00000000;
    ANSEL = 0b00000000;
    GPIO = 0b00000000;

    while(1) {
        GP2 = 1;
        GP5 = 1;
        __delay_ms(500);
        GP2 = 0;
        GP5 = 0;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
}
```

For context, while I'm not necessarily *new* to writing code, I'm by *no* means experienced.

Comment: What frequency sine wave?

Comment: My multimeter said it was about 2MHz, but it could change based on what was connected to that pin. For instance, when I only had the scope on it, the wave was a higher frequency, but when the multimeter was connected as well, it visibly changed lower in frequency. If I touched the pin (via a jumper), the frequency could go low enough to even hear on a speaker.

Comment: Read the end of your `#pragma config FOSC` line...

Answer (score 2):

This chip has *so many functions* multiplexed on that **one** pin, that you must work hard to configure it as GP4 digital output.
It appears that your config line `#pragma config FOSC = EXTRCCLK` forces that GP4 pin to be a clock output, and disables digital output function. As @brhans has suggested, look at the compilers config output to verify. In the diagram below, **CLKOUT** appears to be derived from CONFIG:
[image: I/O configuration]

You have properly disabled Analog Input mode for the Analog-to-digital and CMCON1 seems proper. It might be wise to add:

```
CMCON1 = 0b00000000;
```

Comment: I can't say how many hours I've spent trying to get IO pins working on PICs that were set up as analogue by default ...